# PHPExcel date not appearing

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to format a PHP date() object into a format that Excel can read as a date rather than as a string.

```
$row[] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(date('d-m-y', strtotime($worksheet_one_job['Job']['date_of_order'])));
$worksheet_one->fromArray($row, NULL, $columnID.$rowID);
```

The format of the field `$worksheet_one_job['Job']['date_of_order']` in the database is DateTime (2016-06-28 00:00:00)

When I check this in Excel it prints nothing at all, any ideas how I can set the cell as a date format that Excel can read rather than as a string?